# Firestore can't convert Document toObject

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve a Document but I just can't get it to work. Here is my Code:

```
fm.getColRefProgramms().document(programmKey).collection("items").document("HIXQobZtlMxn4OblgOMi").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    String s = documentSnapshot.getId();
                    OverviewItem item = documentSnapshot.toObject(OverviewItem.class);
                    item.setKey(item.getKey());
                }
            });
```

String s return the correct Id, so the Document is found and loaded from the Database but it can´t create a OverviewIdem Object from it.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
```

And this is the OverviewItem Class:

```
public class OverviewItem implements IProgrammItem, Serializable{

private String instance;
private String key;
private Programm programm;
private ArrayList<BasicElement> elements;

public OverviewItem() {}

public void setInstance(String instance) {
    this.instance = instance;
}

public String getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Exclude
public Programm getProgramm() {
    return programm;
}

@Exclude
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

@Exclude
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

@Exclude
public void setProgramm(Programm programm) {
    this.programm = programm;
}

public ArrayList<BasicElement> getElements() {
    return elements;
}

public void setElements(ArrayList<BasicElement> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
}
}
```

And this is my Document:

[image: Database]

Comment: can you post BasicElement as well?

Comment: Damn it, I forgot the empty constructor in the BasicElement Object. Thanks for the tipp!

Comment: glad I helpd you somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

FIX: I waited for half an hour, then it started to retrieve the data (Date's value was retrieved and wasn't null anymore). Maybe the database takes time to update, so give it some time (if you added a new value or document) and then check again.

I'm facing the same issue. This is my code:

```
        firebasefirestore.collection("events").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for(DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    Map<String, Object> a = doc.getDocument().getData();
                    HomeViewModel event = doc.getDocument().toObject(HomeViewModel.class);
                    eventlist.add(event);
                    eventRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I created a variable 'a' to see the data, and the data is being successfully retrieved from Firestore (I was checking in the debugger).

[Value of a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfeAe.png)

However when I use toObject(), Date is null.

My HomeViewModel class:

```
public class HomeViewModel{

    private String Date;
    private String Description;
    private String Imagepath;
    private String Title;

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.Date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public String getImagepath() {
        return Imagepath;
    }

    public void setImagepath(String imagepath) {
        Imagepath = imagepath;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public HomeViewModel(){
    }

    public HomeViewModel(String title, String desc, String date, String imagepath) {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Description = desc;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Imagepath = imagepath;
    }

}
```

Therefore it is clear that toObject is the problem.